# Will the MOSFET survive with this negative gate voltage?

Tags: mosfet, datasheet

With [this](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/2N7000-D.PDF) MOSFET the circuit's input is shown below and a function generator will be the input signal to turn on or off. I wonder if some one accidentally applies negative voltage like -10V to the gate would the MOSFET gets damaged?:

[image]

I couldn't infer this from the datasheet specs.

Comment: I see so that is independent from the drain voltage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I couldn't infer this from the datasheet specs.*

Look at the data sheet for the 2N7000 on page 1 - it's right there: -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The datasheet gives you values for maximum gate source voltage, and maximum gate drain voltage, as long as you stay within these parameters, the MOSFET will survive and behave appropriately.

You will have -10 Vgs, and 22 Vdg, so should be ok.